# How to track total number of rejected and dropped events

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the correct way to track number of dropped or rejected events in the managed elasticsearch cluster?

Answer (score 4):

`GET /_nodes/stats/thread_pool` which gives you something like:

```
         "thread_pool": {
            "bulk": {
               "threads": 4,
               "queue": 0,
               "active": 0,
               "rejected": 0,
               "largest": 4,
               "completed": 42
            }
....
            "flush": {
               "threads": 0,
               "queue": 0,
               "active": 0,
               "rejected": 0,
               "largest": 0,
               "completed": 0
            }
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get more concise and better formatted info (especially if you are dealing with several nodes) about thread pools is to use the [`_cat` threadpool API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-thread-pool.html)

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v'
host        ip          bulk.active bulk.queue bulk.rejected index.active index.queue index.rejected search.active search.queue search.rejected 
10.10.1.1 10.10.1.1           1         10             0            2           0              0            10            0               0 
10.10.1.2 10.10.1.2           2          0             1            4           0              0             4           10               2 
10.10.1.3 10.10.1.3           1          0             0            1           0              0             5            0               0
```

**UPDATE**

You can also decide [which thread pools to show](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-thread-pool.html#_available_thread_pools) and for each thread pool [which fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-thread-pool.html#_thread_pool_fields) to include in the output. For instance below, we're showing the following fields from the search threadpool:

- `sqs`: The maximum number of search requests that can be queued before being rejected
- `sq`: The number of search requests in the search queue
- `sa`: The number of currently active search threads
- `sr`: The number of rejected search threads (since the last restart)
- `sc`: The number of completed search threads (since the last restart)

Here is the command:

```
curl -s -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v&h=ip,sqs,sq,sa,sr,sc'
ip           sqs sq sa  sr        sc 
10.10.1.1    100  0  1   0  62636120 
10.10.1.2    100  0  2   0  15528863 
10.10.1.3    100  0  4   0  64647299 
10.10.1.4    100  0  5 372 103014657 
10.10.1.5    100  0  2   0  13947055
```

Comment: Ha :-), I forgot about this one.

Comment: "All roads lead to Rome", indeed! +1 for yours ;-)

Comment: Is it showing the "total" of all events that were sent to elastic search or periodic?

Comment: You can add the `search.completed` and `bulk.completed` headers (using the `h=...`query string parameter) which will show the total number of events sent to ES since the last restart

Comment: @Val Could you please elaborate how to add said headers?

Comment: Is there anything else you need?